# Rails-admin-scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

Пытался использовать [гем](https://github.com/dhampik/rails-admin-scaffold) , но видимо он багнутый. Я конечно же не хочу пользоваться нативными шаблонами, и попытался кастомизировать. Происходит то, что гем как бы не подхватывает мои шаблоны, хотя они и лежат в нужном месте. Есть решение?

Comment: Пожалуйста, конкретизируйте ошибку. Из текущего описания непонятно, в чем она состоит, равно как и то, чего вы пытаетесь достичь.

Comment: Я Пытаюсь использовать вышеуказанынй гем, я разместил темплейты по указанному пути, но кастомизация темплейтов не произходит :(

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться гемом rails_admin: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Comment: Нет, я хочу именно кастомить скаффолды)